# Pass String Array Varaible from Command Line (.BAT file) to Power Shell Script

Tags: arrays, shell, powershell

I am trying to pass an array %variable% from command line to power shell and then perform operations with this array variable within power shell but I am having trouble passing the variable to power shell correctly. Current .BAT script to call power shell script is below...

```
SET STRING_ARRAY="test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "FILEPATH\Build_DB.ps1" %STRING_ARRAY%
```

Then power shell script below to test for a sucessful handover of the array varaible is as follows:

```
$string_array=@($args[0])

Write-Host $string_array.length

for ($i=0; $i -lt $string_array.length; $i++) {
    Write-Host $string_array[$i]
}
```

However all is returned is a length of 1 from power shell. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, never mind I ended up coming up with a solution that works in my case so I am posting it here in case it is of benefit to anyone else. If someone has a better solution please let me know.

Change the power shell script as follows:

```
#The problem is that each item in the %STRING_ARRAY% variable is passed as
#an individual argument to power shell. To get around this we can just 
#store all optional arguments passed to power shell as follows.
$string_array=@($args)

#Now (if desired) we can also remove any optional arguments we don't want 
#in our new array using the following command.
$string_array = $string_array[2..($string_array.Length)]

Write-Host $string_array.length

for ($i=0; $i -lt $string_array.length; $i++) {
    Write-Host $string_array[$i]
}
```